# php function error expects parameter 2 to be long, array

Tags: php, arrays, function, warnings

Hi i have a problem using the function of the APCu Cache system "apcu_cas" http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-cas.php
I have an array stored in a cache key, while i'm trying to update the value of the key with a new array i get this error:

```
Warning: apcu_cas() expects parameter 2 to be long, array on line apcu_cas($cache_key, $data, $value);
```

My Code :

```
$value = array(
   "first_name" => "John",
   "last_name" => "Doe"
);
$cache_key = "my_cached_key";
$result = false;
$data = apcu_fetch($cache_key, $result);
if(!$result){
   //is not cached, so i add it
   apcu_add($cache_key, $value, 600);//10min
}else{
   //data is cached, i update it
   apcu_cas($cache_key, $data, $value);     
}
```

Comment: From the docs `apc_cas() updates an already existing integer value if the old parameter matches the currently stored value with the value of the new parameter.` - it looks like you can only use this for integers. `apc_store()` looks like it's what you need to use.

Comment: Did you try the manual page for the function?

Comment: @andrewsi I've read some tutorials saying you can update string and arrays too. It seems not :/ a bit weird..

Comment: So the error saying has to be long means it has to be a long integer?

Comment: @yves - Yes, a long in this case is a long int. It looks like the tutorials you're following are either out of date, or just plain inaccurate, alas.

Comment: It seems. Ok thanks for enlightening me. I will try with the apc_store otherwise i will delete the cached key an add it again instead of using the function. Thanks :) Have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apcu_cas($cache_key, $data, $value);` here is the error. The second parameter ($data) is an array and not an integer. See documentation: `bool apc_cas ( string $key , int $old , int $new )`